# html / css responsive grid that resizes and fills width properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am sure this problem has a simple answer, and I over complicating this! If I am, then I apologize in advance!

I want to have a grid of divs that fill the width of a container div. Say 8 div blocks, in two rows of 4, 25% each of the parent div.

On resizing the width down, the divs should shrink in width (fixed height) until a min-width is reached. The divs should then wrap / float to become three rows of 3, 3 and 2.

I have all this working fine. My simplified code is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

<style>
.container {
width: 90%;
}
.box {
margin: 10px;
width: 22%;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 22%;
height: 300px;
background: #ff0000;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<body>

<div align="center">
<div class="container">

<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that on each jump from 4 columns to 3 to 2 to 1, the divs stay at their minimum width and no longer fill the full parent width.

What I am trying to achieve is that the divs will always fill the parent width.

Any solution I have found so far is massively over complicated with jquery and many plugins, doing all sorts of other features as well.

The only feature I am trying to achieve is this fluid width of the child divs.

I am currently using html and css, but am fine with using a jquery or other solution, but don't want to use html5 or css3.

Comment: you can use bootstrap plugin to achieve this easily. refer these links http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp and http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insteed of using max-width for the effect you want I would use some very simple media queries.

Basically you change the width of your boxes when the window reaches your desire width and you may use as many steps as you want.

like this:

```
.box {
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0000;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid white;        
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.box {
    width: 33%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.box {
    width: 50%;
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.box {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Don't use display inline-block as you will always have an extra margin between your boxes that will mess your widths. Float is much better option.

If you use "%" then you shoudn't use margins in pixels if you want perfect results (as your boxes filling always 100% of the container)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w9ms9u4/)

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap makes responsive very easy.
check bootstrap here : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/